# how to get an integer from JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, ios5

im parsing a JSON and cant seem to extract an integer. If i do

```
  int  secondsLeft = [secondsList objectForKey:@"SecondsToStop"];
```

if I do NSLog(@"%@",secondsLeft) it does however get outputted correctly in the console, but im unsure how to get a proper integer. Whats the proper way to parse numbers from a JSON object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your JSON parsing framework probably stored the number as an NSNumber.

According to [the NSNumber documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/), you can call `intValue` on the number to get its value as a plain old int:

```
int secondsLeft = [[secondsList objectForKey:@"SecondsToTop"] intValue];
```